# Why does finding empty string return 0?

Tags: python, string

I am trying to figure out a string problem in Python.
So this is from the online course [Building A Search Engine](http://www.udacity.com/overview/Course/cs101/) and in the quiz there is a problem:

**For any string `s = '<any string>'`, which of the following always has value 0?**

- (a) `s.find(s)`
- (b) `s.find('s')`
- (c) `'s'.find('s')`
- (d) `s.find('')`
- (e) `s.find(s+'!!!')+1`

**Answer:** (a), (c), (d) & (e)

And I am pretty sure about other choices except for choice (d).

I think the output should be `-1` but the output is `0`.

[image: output]

So my reasoning follows:

`s` is the predefined question before but `''` should be considered as an empty string. So in a string to find an empty string, why not the returning is not `-1` because you can not find empty in any string.

==============================================

OK, I can see my wrong thinking.

In the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in),

> Empty strings are always considered to be a substring of any other string, so "" in "abc" will return `True`.

Comment: An empty string is a subset of any string, just like an empty set is a subset of any set. Moreover, any string starts with an empty string. That's why.

Comment: _"you can not find empty in any string"_ Of course you can. You can find it literally everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [**`string.find(s, sub[, start[, end]])`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) document says:

> Return the lowest index in `s` where the substring `sub` is found such that `sub` is wholly contained in `s[start:end]`.

The way Python interpreter performs the search is by looking for your substring from the `start` index of the string and going till the `end` index.

It iterates and compares your substring as:

```
your_string[i:i+len(substring)]
# where `i` is the index
```

for your case, your substring is having `0` length, and with string slicing with `0`th index at end, it returned empty string. For example:

```
>>> your_string = 'abcd'
>>> your_string[0:0]
''
```

Hence, when you executed `str.find` with *empty string* on it, you got the result as `0`

```
>>> your_string.find('')
0

# Because your_string[0:0] == ''
#                     ^  this being the index returned
```

Comment: Thank you for the classifying. Now I see, find works with the loop of the string.